# Brace matching within strings in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I recently discovered that Netbeans highlights matching braces within strings when you place your cursor on one of them. Even if these strings are spread over different calls to for example a file writer.

e.g.

```
writer.append(" ( <- this");
writer.append(" matches this -> ) ");
```

IntelliJ does not have this feature enabled by default, if it has this feature at all. So the question is: does IntelliJ have this feature? And if so, how does one enable it?

Comment: No, it doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use 'Language Injections' feature https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/using-language-injections.html

If you select, for example, 'Plain text' then IntelliJ will highlight breces inside one String.

Comment: TIL this is a thing. It's a bit overkill for my current project, but it's good to know that such a tool exists.

Comment: @user1903443 Why overkill? It is a just one comment to enable it :)


`//language=TEXT`